# Funny response of field data with ++ operator C#

Tags: c#, properties

I've got a program snippet here that allows the creation of an Employee object with simple properties of age, id, name and pay.  Just playing around with it I noticed that

```
 Console.WriteLine(joe.Age+1); is my Main() method returns one,
```

but `Console.WriteLine(joe.Age++);` returns 0.  I know that the Age property, per the constructors is going to be initialized to 0, but why isn't 1 being added with the ++ operator?  **EDIT: I found the source of the strange behavior.  In the Age property I have `empAge=Age` when it should've been equal to `value`**

source:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace EmployeeApp
{
    class Employee
    {
        //field data
        //notice the the fields are declared as private
        //these fields are used in the constructors
        private string empName;
        private int empID;
        private float currPay;
        private int empAge;

        //properties! private field data should be accessed via public properties
        //note that properties don't use parentheses ()
        //within the set scope you see the 'value' contextual keyword
        //it represents the value being assigned by the caller and it will always be the same 
        //underlying data type as the property itself
        public int Age
        {
            get { return empAge; }
            set { empAge = Age; }
        }


        public string Name
        {
            get { return empName; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length > 15)
                    Console.WriteLine("this name is too long.");
                else
                    empName = value;
            }
        }
        public int ID
        {
            get { return empID; }
            set { empID = value; }
        }
        public float pay
        {
            get { return currPay; }
            set { currPay = value; }
        }

        //constructors
        public Employee() { }

        public Employee(string name, int id, float pay, int age)
        {
            empName = name;
            empID = id;
            currPay = pay;
            empAge = age;
        }

        //methods
        //the int parameter that this method takes will come from somewhere in the Main method
        //currpay is a private field
        public void GiveBonus(float amount)
        {
            currPay += amount;
        }
        public void DisplayStats()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("name: {0}", empName);
            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", empID);
            Console.WriteLine("pay: {0}", currPay);
            Console.WriteLine("age: {0}", empAge);
        }
    }

}
```

Main method here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//Encapsulation using traditional accessors/mutators or get/set methods
//the role of a get method is to return to the caller the current value of the underlying state data
//a set method allows the caller ot change the current value of the state data

//you need to have a getter and a setter for every field that the class has

namespace EmployeeApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("fun with encapsulation");
            //Employee emp = new Employee("marvin", 456, 4000, 56);
            //emp.GiveBonus(3);
           // emp.DisplayStats();
           // emp.Name = "wilson";
           // emp.DisplayStats();

            Employee joe = new Employee();

            Console.WriteLine(joe.Age++);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `thing++` is a post-operation, not pre-operation, so to speak.

Comment: Execute `Console.WriteLine(joe.Age++);` many times and see the result

Comment: i did, it's 0 every time. that's why i asked the question :)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie unless you create a new `Employee` in each iteration, it can not be zero everytime.

Comment: @L.B see the edit.  I made the mistake declaring the Age property, it wasn't set to `value` and that's what was causing the strange behavior.

Comment: @L.B it can if the code doesn't actually change the variable :)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie exactly, I pointed that out below in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Age property, you are not changing the `empAge` member to the value passed in.  This is probably why you aren't seeing any changes when you tried [`++`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx) multiple times.

```
public int Age 
{ 
    get { return empAge; } 
    set { empAge = Age;  } // this does not set the value!
}
```

Use the `value` instead:

```
public int Age 
{ 
    get { return empAge;   } 
    set { empAge = value;  } // use the value passed in
}
```

And as others have pointed out, you are using the postfix version of the `++` operator.  The prefix version will increment the amount first before writing the property to the console.

Comment: missed this, you were correct.  credit is given where it was due.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this.

Answer (score 4):

The `++` incremental operator has two uses:

```
joe.Age++
```

and

```
++joe.Age
```

The first one, as you're using, is executed *after* the current operation. So, when you call `Console.WriteLine(joe.Age++);`, this can also be represented with:

```
Console.WriteLine(joe.Age);
joe.Age = joe.Age + 1;
```

So, you're passing the current value to `WriteLine`, and *then* incrementing it.

Leading with `++` will do the opposite - increment and *then* use the value. So, `Console.WriteLine(++joe.Age);` can also be read as:

```
joe.Age = joe.Age + 1;
Console.WriteLine(joe.Age);
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use the [unary ++ operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx) after the variable, the addition doesn't happen until after the outer expression is evaluated. When you use it before the variable, the addition happens before the outer expression is evaluated.

For instance,

```
// this will increment joe.Age, and then write it to console.
Console.WriteLine(++joe.Age);
```

versus

```
// this will write joe.Age to the console, and then increment it.
Console.WriteLine(joe.Age++);
```

From the [docs on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx):

> The first form is a prefix increment operation. The result of the
>   operation is the value of the operand after it has been incremented.
>
> The second form is a postfix increment operation. The result of the
>   operation is the value of the operand before it has been incremented.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ and C#, there are two ++ operators.  The first is a prefix operator (++age) and this one works as you are expecting -- increments the value and then returns the result.  the postfix operator (age++) increments the value but returns the *previous* value.